# Summing Columns Between Timestamp/Newline Delimiters Using Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, awk, sed

I have data in the form of:

```
23:31:39
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.7 0.0 1:38.52
20 0 43064 20112 4484 R 0.8 0.1 0:00.12
20 0 27116 5152 3856 S 0.3 0.0 0:00.05
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
23:31:54
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.7 0.0 1:38.93
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
23:32:09
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.6 0.0 1:39.32
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
23:32:24
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.9 0.0 1:39.76
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
```

Data above alternates b/w timestamp line and then rows of data to be summed.

I want to sum columns in the lines under each timestamp so that when I add say...column 1 what I get would look like:

```
23:31:39
80
23:31:54
40
23:32:09
40
23:32:24
40
```

And when I add columns 1 and 7, I get:

```
23:31:39
80 3.8
23:31:54
40 2.7
23:32:09
40 2.6
23:32:24
40 2.9
```

How would I manipulate the data this way? I'm trying to get it into a form that I can easily plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an awk solution, which you can probably adapt to your needs.

It actually produces a single line for each timestamp/aggregate, because that is usually easier to plot. But it would be easy to change the output format.

```
# file: aggregate.awk
#
# Call this as follows:
# awk -v columns=1,7 -f aggregate.awk data.file
BEGIN {
    ncols = split(columns, cols, /,/);
}
function print_line() {
    if (ts != "") {
        printf "%s", ts;
        for (i = 1; i <= ncols; ++i) printf " %f", data[i];
        printf "\n";
    }
}

/^..:..:../ {
    print_line();
    ts = $0;
    for (i = 1; i <= ncols; ++i) data[i] = 0;
    next;
}
    { for (i = 1; i <= ncols; ++i) data[i] += $(cols[i]); }
END { print_line(); }
```

Example:

```
$ awk -v columns=1,7 -f aggregate.awk <<EOF
23:31:39
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.7 0.0 1:38.52
20 0 43064 20112 4484 R 0.8 0.1 0:00.12
20 0 27116 5152 3856 S 0.3 0.0 0:00.05
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
23:31:54
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.7 0.0 1:38.93
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
23:32:09
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.6 0.0 1:39.32
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
23:32:24
20 0 24436 404 56 R 2.9 0.0 1:39.76
20 0 24952 4672 3708 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05
EOF

23:31:39 80 3.8
23:31:54 40 2.7
23:32:09 40 2.6
23:32:24 40 2.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `perl` alternative to @rici's answer. Note that array indexes start at 0, so this example with your data uses columns 0 and 6 instead of 1 and 7.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @wanted_cols = (0,6);

my %sums;

while (<>) {
    my @cols = split /\s+/;
    if ($#cols) {
        foreach my $w (@wanted_cols) { $sums{$w} += $cols[$w] }
    } else {
        print join("\t", @sums{ @wanted_cols }), "\n";
        %sums = ();
        print $_;
    }
}
print join("\t", @sums{ @wanted_cols }), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk ' NF==1 { if(NR>1) print p,t1,t7 ;p=$0 ; t1=t7=0 } NF!=1 { t1+=$1;t7+=$7 } END { print p,t1,t7 }  ' mnot.txt
23:31:39 80 3.8
23:31:54 40 2.7
23:32:09 40 2.6
23:32:24 40 2.9
$
```